# upgrade ember addon on ember-cli 0.2.2

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I started developing an addon in on ember-cli `0.2.1` and when I generated my files using the generator, they placed the files in `~/app/` and not `~/addon`.

What do I need to do put the files in the right place?

The project contains services, mixins and utils with tests covering them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the default behavior for a good reason: the generators are meant to be used in context of an application. You should consider your `addon/` folder being sort of a `lib` directory, where you can use any file/folder structure that fits the best to your addon. The `app/` folder, however, is meant to contain the re-exported modules, so they'll become available on the host app's container automatically.

Browse around a few well-written addons to find out how most people do this, a good example is the `ember-radio-button`

- Here are [all the modules](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-radio-button/tree/master/addon/components)
- Then the [only necessary modules](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-radio-button/tree/master/app/components) are re-exported.

Notice that an abstact class like [`radio-button-base`](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-radio-button/blob/master/addon/components/radio-button-base.js) is useless by itself, and, therefore, unnecessary to reside on the container, but an addon user would want to import and extend it for his own purposes, which he can do by writing `import RadioButtonBase from 'ember-radio-button/components/radio-button-base';`